# How to split string based on number of characters using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take one string and split it into different chunks, and place it inside divs.  Here's my code:

```
var simple = '<?php echo $hallo; ?>';     
var $div = $('#mybook');

if ($div.text().length > 50) {
    var limit = simple.lenght = 10;
    $(simple.split(limit)).each(function() {
        $('#mybook').append('<div>'+this+'</div>')
    });
}
```

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) doesn't take a number, it takes a string delimiter that tells the function where to create the chunks.

Comment: So is there another way to do this? how?

Comment: It's good practice to end your JS statements with a semicolon `;`. Some of your statements end with it, others don't.

Comment: @Aaron: It depends on exactly what you're trying to do. Could you add an example input string and what the expected output would be?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker he's trying to limit the string size to some size. The extra characters would go into a new div. For example let's say there's a limit of 2 characters and a string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. The result should be `<div>ab</div><div>cd</div>` and so on. At least that's what seems he's looking for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var simple = '<?php echo $hallo; ?>';
var $div = $('#mybook');
if($div.text().length > 50) {
    var limit = simple.lenght = 10;
    var regex = new RegExp('.{1,'+limit+'}','g')
    $(simple.match(regex)).each(function(key,val){
        $('#mybook').append('<div>'+val+'</div>')
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ugh, it worked nicely! tbh, this is what i love about this site. Both answers actually worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just split your string with a regex, not with `split`

```
$(simple.match('/.{'+limit+'}|.{,'+(limit-1)+'}$/g')).each(function() {

    $('#mybook').append('<div>'+this+'</div>')

});
```